# How to finish this Epsilon Delta Proof?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was asked to use the definition of limit to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 1}  \frac{2x}{3x-1} = 1$$

The problem is, once I reach a certain point, specifically with solving for epsilon, I get caught at $$\frac{|x-1|}{|3x-1|}$$ I also have trouble finding a $\delta$.

Help please?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{2x}{3x-1}=\frac{2x-2/3+2/3}{3x-1}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3(3x-1)}$

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off to a good start! Here's an idea: figure out some $c>0$ such that $\frac1{|3x-1|}<1$ whenever $|x-1|<c,$ and then let $\delta=\min\{c,\epsilon\}.$

Answer (score 2):

(1) $\lim_{x\to\ 1}\frac{2x}{3x-1} = 1$

(2) This says, given $\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon$ whenever, $0<|x-1|<\delta$.

(3) So, $|f(x)-f(1)| = |\frac{2x}{3x-1}-1|= \frac{|x-1|}{|3x-1|}$.

(4) Suppose $|x-1|<\delta\leq 2 \Rightarrow -1\leq x\leq3$

(5) From (4) we get, $\frac{|x-1|}{|3x-1|}\leq \frac{\delta}{4}$

(6) Taking $\delta$=min{$1,4\epsilon$} should do it.